# No schemas have been found | XJC

Tags: maven, xsd, jaxb2

Can someone please help me on this issue. I have more than 2 schema files in the same directory and trying to generate the java classes using xjc in maven.

Here is my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb2.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                        <schemaFiles>${root.dir}/schemas/PnTCacheSchema.xsd</schemaFiles>
                        <schemaDirectory>${root.dir}/schemas/</schemaDirectory>
                        <packageName>com.superpages.nbt.gen.pnt</packageName>
                        <outputDirectory>${root.dir}/nbt/src</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc1</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                        <schemaFiles>${root.dir}/schemas/AdCacheSchema.xsd</schemaFiles>
                        <schemaDirectory>${root.dir}/schemas/</schemaDirectory>
                        <packageName>com.superpages.nbt.gen.cache</packageName>
                        <outputDirectory>${root.dir}/nbt/src</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Getting this exception

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:1.6:xjc (default-cli) on project gypsygen: No schemas have been found -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try enclosing `<plugins>` tag inside `<pluginManagement> tag.`